# PHP validation error logic error

Tags: php

I have a signup form in PHP and I am doing an ajax request to my PHP page to verify all the fields and insert the data into my database. But again and again, it's throwing me an error on the very first echo statement "Please enter all the fields". though I am filling al the input fields.
Help is appreciated.Please let me know as well that the below code is safe to use or not.

```
 $username= filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userName", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userEmail", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$password=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userpassword",FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING);
$verifyPassword=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"verifyPassword",FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING);


if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($verifyPassword)){
    echo "Please enter all the fields";
}
else if($password !== $verifyPassword){
    echo "Password doesn't match";
}
else{
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT userEmail FROM regularUser WHERE userEmail = :email");
    $stmt1->bindParam("email", $email) ;
    $stmt1->execute();
    $result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count = $result1->rowCount();
        if($count > 1)
        {
            echo "Email already exist";
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO regularUser(userEmail,userName,userPassword) VALUES (:email,:name,:password)");  
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $email) ;
            $stmt->bindParam("name", $username) ;
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $stmt->bindParam("hash_password", $hash) ;
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "success";   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Empty in PHP, is more then not filled in. empty is `false` `null` `0` `'0'` `''` `[]` etc.

Comment: You've already filtered your fields at that stage. What data are you sending? Have you tried debugging your `$_POST`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am sending the user sign up credentials through the ajax request to this php page

Comment: You need more granular error checking, `all fields tells you, and it would tell a user nothing` I would suggest checking each field recording in an array and then output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($verifyPassword)){
    echo "Please enter all the fields";
}
else if($password !== $verifyPassword){
    echo "Password doesn't match";
}
```

To

```
$errors = [];

if(empty($username)) $errors[] = 'Please enter a username';
if(empty($email)) $errors[] = 'Please enter an email';
if(empty($password)) $errors[] = 'Please enter a password';
if(empty($verifyPassword)) $errors[] = 'Please enter a verify password';
if($password !== $verifyPassword) $errors[] = 'Password doesn\'t match';

if(count($errors) > 0) echo implode("\n", $username); //or <br>
```

Think about it this way, if you are having trouble finding what fields, your end users will too.

While this doesn't fix your problem, it will tell you what field is empty.

There are many ways to do this, but you should always strive to give your users as much info as possible, without interfering with security.

Comment: Sure, it was nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var_dump()` to check `$username` , `$email`, `$password` , `$verifyPassword` .

You can see they are `string`, `array`, or `Object`

in some cases, `empty()` is not true!

You should use:

- `Empty()` for `Array`
- `is_null()` for `object` or `string`
- `!=''` for `string`

Comment: `empty()` is perfectly appropriate for strings and is far easier to type than `if (isset($_POST['var']) && $_POST['var'] != '')`.

Comment: in the past, i got a big wrong with using empty() for checking string "" or null object (i dont remember) .so i think his trouble is the same, hihi

Comment: Of course, if you're doing `empty("")` or `empty(null)` it's going to return `true`. You need to know what you're checking and [how PHP compares different types](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).